# How to getting multiple attributes of a variable in a netCDF file at a time?

Tags: r, netcdf

I am checking the meta data of a batch of netCDF files in R. As SO doesn't seem to allow file upload, I have attached the header of a simplified example netCDF file below:

```
netcdf no2 {
dimensions:
    lon = 360 ;
    lat = 179 ;
    time = UNLIMITED ; // (10 currently)
variables:
    double lon(lon) ;
        lon:units = "degsE" ;
    double lat(lat) ;
        lat:units = "degsN" ;
    int time(time) ;
        time:units = "days since 1900-01-01" ;
    float no2(time, lat, lon) ;
        no2:units = "ug/m3" ;
        no2:missing_value = 1.e+30f ;
        no2:long_name = "nitrogen dioxide" ;
        no2:standard_name = "no2" ;
}
```

Basically, I tried to get several attributes of the variable, e.g., "standard_name", "long_name" and "units" of "no2", at a time into a vector. However, `att.get.ncdf()` in Package `ncdf` seemed to only allow one at a time. As it could be rather tedious and laborious to get more attributes by repeating the code, I reckon there must be a neater way of doing it, but I just failed to find it on Google. Could someone share their experience with me, please?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ncdf` seems don't provide a method to get all attributes of a variable. But if you know the attributes, you can get them using a loop or `sapply`.

For example:

```
filename <- "no2"
nc <- open.ncdf( filename )
var <- "no"
attrs <- c('standard_name','long_name','units','missing_value')
sapply(attrs,function(x)
   att.get.ncdf( nc, var, x)$value)
close.ncdf(nc)

standard_name          long_name              units      missing_value 
         "no2" "nitrogen dioxide"            "ug/m3"             "1200"
```